# Biométrico DigitalPersona en Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, nodejs, webforms

Tengo mi biométrico de DigitalPerson U.are.U 4500 y su SDK funciona perfectamente con mi WindowsForm C#, pero ahora necesito implementarlo en la Web usando WebForms he incluido el SDK y las mismas líneas que utilicé en el WindowsForms, pero desafortunadamente no me funciona.

¿Alguien ha implementado alguna manera de utilizar biométricos usado WebForms o en su defecto NodeJS para poder leer las DLLs o llamar mediante parámetros mi .exe generado?

Este es mi código:

```
    using DPFP.Capture;
    using DPFP.Processing;
    using DPFP.Verification;

     namespace WebBiometrico
     {
   public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page,DPFP.Capture.EventHandler
    {

    Enrollment Enroller = new Enrollment();
    Capture Capturer;
    Verification Verificator = new Verification();
    protected static IMongoClient cliente = new MongoClient();
    protected static IMongoDatabase data = cliente.GetDatabase("base_datos");
    private DPFP.Template Template;
    delegate void Function();

    protected virtual void Initando()
    {
        Capturer = new Capture();
        if (null != Capturer)
            Capturer.EventHandler = this;
        else
            Label1.Text = "No es posible Inicar la Operacion de Captura!";
        try
        { }
        catch
        {
            Label1.Text = "No es posible Inicar la Operacion de Captura";
        }
    }
    protected void Start()
    {
        if (null != Capturer)
        {
            try
            {
                Capturer.StartCapture();
                Label1.Text = "Use el lector para escanear su huella digital.";
            }
            catch
            {
                Label1.Text = "No se puede iniciar la captura!";
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Stop()
    {
        if (null != Capturer)
        {
            try
            {
                Capturer.StopCapture();
            }
            catch
            {
                Label1.Text = "No es posible terminar!";
            }
        }
    }
    #region sinuso
    public void OnSampleQuality(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback CaptureFeedback)
    {
        if (CaptureFeedback == DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.Good)
            Label1.Text = "Buena Calidad.";
        else
            Label1.Text = "Mala Calidad";
    }
    public void OnFingerGone(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }

    public void OnFingerTouch(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }

    public void OnReaderConnect(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }

    public void OnReaderDisconnect(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }
    #endregion

    public void OnComplete(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, DPFP.Sample Sample)
    {
        leeRutas(this, Sample);
    }

    private void leeRutas(Default frm, DPFP.Sample Sample)
    {
        var coleccion = data.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("empleados");
        var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
        var resultado = coleccion.Find(filtro).FirstOrDefault();
        if (resultado != null)
        {
            FileStream fsTG = File.OpenRead(resultado["ruta"].ToString());
            DPFP.Template templateGuardado = new DPFP.Template(fsTG);
            if (procesar(Sample, templateGuardado, frm) == "Bienvenido")
            {
                Label2.Text = "Bienvenido ";
            }
            else
            {
                Label2.Text = "Ha Ocurrido un Error Administrador";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text = "El resultado es Nulo";
        }
    }
    private string procesar(DPFP.Sample Sample, DPFP.Template templateGuardado, Default frm)
    {
        DrawPicture(ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample), frm);
        DPFP.FeatureSet features = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification);
        if (features != null)
        {
            DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result result = new DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result();
            Verificator.Verify(features, templateGuardado, ref result);
            if (result.Verified)
            {
                return "Bienvenido";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Falla";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Falla";
        }
    }
    public DPFP.FeatureSet ExtractFeatures(DPFP.Sample Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose Purpose)
    {
        FeatureExtraction Extractor = new FeatureExtraction();
        CaptureFeedback feedback = CaptureFeedback.None;
        DPFP.FeatureSet features = new DPFP.FeatureSet();
        Extractor.CreateFeatureSet(Sample, Purpose, ref feedback, ref features);            // TODO: return features as a result?
        if (feedback == CaptureFeedback.Good)
            return features;
        else
            return null;
    }

    private void OnTemplate(DPFP.Template template)
    {
        Template = template;
        if (Template != null)
            Label1.Text = "El Dispositivo esta Listo para la Verificacion";
        else
            Label1.Text = "Dispositivo Fuera de Linea";

    }

    public Bitmap ConvertSampleToBitmap(DPFP.Sample Sample)
    {
        SampleConversion Convertor = new DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Convertor.ConvertToPicture(Sample, ref bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void DrawPicture(Bitmap bitmap, Default frm)
    {

           Picture.Image = new Bitmap(bitmap, Picture.Size);//   Asi lo Hago en Windows forms, no entiendo su equivalencia en WebForms
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Initando();
            Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            Label1.Text = "No se puede iniciar la captura!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: y si agregas el código?

Comment: Hola. Debes diferenciar el entorno web con el de una aplicación Windows. Para poder realizar lo que que quieres, acceder a los recursos del cliente a través de un browser, deberás implementar un control Activex/COM e instalarlo en todas tus maquinas cliente. Te recomiendo leas la documentación del SDK. Saludos

Comment: En la Documentación no viene el Activex.. =(

Comment: Descarga aquí el manual de ActiveX/COM [One Touch® for Windows® SDK
COM/ActiveX® Edition](http://www.crossmatch.com/uploadedFiles/Support/Reference_Material/Guides/SDK_Guides/One-Touch-for-Windows-SDK-COM-ActiveX-Developer-Guide.pdf)

Comment: Muchas Gracias....

Comment: Aun Sigo sin poder incluirlo en la Web

Comment: Para resolverlo debes armar un plan e identificar los pasos a seguir. Como te comentaba @SergioParra hay una gran diferencia entre un aplicacion o enterno web y una aplicacion de escritorio. Entonces tu primera pregunta es ¿como accedo desde el navegador a un recurso cliente? En este caso tu hardware. Ese es el paso mas importante, adicionalmente en el SDK debe haber documentacion para este caso o quizas alguien ya intento hacer algo pero antes de preguntar aqui, que es para resolver errores específicos te invito a intentarlo y con gusto te ayudaremos!

Comment: Seguire Intentando, una opcion que tenia en cuenta era seguir con mi aplicacion desktop pero mediante Restful hacer las operaciones necesarias para tenerlo WEB

Comment: Otra opción que tengo un poco mas desarrollada es mediante NodeJS llamar mi .exe, le envio el Id que sera asignado al usuario a enrolar, posteriormente realiza la captura de Huella y la retorna mediante socket.io a Node.

Comment: @Rastalovely esa ultima alternativa que has dicho, me parece una buena opcion, puedes incluso registrar una URI Schema en el sistema operativo para invocar la aplicaicion (el .exe) directo desde tu web app. Luego desde el exe envias un mensaje al servidor autorizando al usuario y le retornas "el token" (por algun medio, socket.io u otros) a la web app para que siga funcionando. Igualmente no te olvides que una huella digital es una contraseña que no puedes cambiar y que dejas impresa en todo lo que tocas XD. Salu2 Mira aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo hace un mes y algo realize el manejo de un dispositivo checador biometrico, su sdk estaba en C# y yo queria controlarlo en tiempo real con Node.js y websockets, la forma en que realize eso fue compliar la aplicacion en c# y usarla como template para asi poder usarla con n numero de checadores.

La forma en que lo hice fue que la apliacion .exe hecha en C# se conectara por medio de tcp a un servidor tcp en Node.js y asi este enviarlo al front-end por medio de socket.io.

No se si estoy en la misma corriente de lo que quieres hacer, pero seria una buena opcion si quieres comunicar el .exe de C# con una aplicacion web.

No puedo mostrar el codigo porque esta privado en el repositorio y fue para un trabajo. Si tienes alguna duda o quieres consultar como podrias hacer la parte de Node.js puedes comincarte conmigo.

[@benjachomin en twitter](https://twitter.com/benjaChomin)

Comment: Pondre en contacto contigo Benjamin, mientras muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya esta funcionando el biometrico en una aplicacion stand alone lo que me ocurre es que convierta esa aplicacion en un servicio de ida y vuelta ejemplo un servicio web socket o un signalR de forma tal que cuando ocurran eventos de huella, haya un evento que le indique a la web que hay huella, y la web pueda ir por ella y asi quedaria reutilizable